If $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that the following equation has at least two real roots.
If $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$, show that the equation
$(x^2+px+3q)(x^2+rx+q)(-x^2+sx+2q)=0$ has at least two real roots.
This question is taken from the book Pathfinder for Olympiad Mathematics by Vikash Tiwari. I had a thought that this question could be solved with a proof by contradiction. The problem I face is that the question does not mention anything about roots having multiplicity. I have, however, assumed that each of the quadratics has roots of multiplicity $2$ which, unfortunately, I am unable to prove. Here is what I have done so far:
Let us assume that this expression has one real root of multiplicity $2$ and rest are complex. Then,
$p^2\geq 12q$
$r^2<4q$ and
$s^2<-8q$
which leads to a contradiction on solving for a square can not be negative.
I do not know whether this proof is satisfactory (whether I must also prove that this expression cannot have all complex roots). I also do not know how to prove that each of the quadratics has roots of multiplicity $2$. Any help, pertaining to this problem, would be greatly appreciated!

What's the point of expanding that expression?

Surely it is better to leave the expression in factored terms.  All you need to show is that at least one of those three quadratics has two real roots.  Note;  not clear to me whether multiplicity is considered.  Does $x^2$ have two real roots or only one?

I wouldn't try to expand and instead reason by absurd: if your equation has at most 1 real root, then by the discriminant argument, all three factors (all of which are quadratics) have a non-positive discriminant, and at least 2 of those discriminants are negative. That gives you three inequalities, which when combined should tell you that a sum of squares is negative.

Just take the discriminates $p^2 - 12q, r^2 -4q, s^2 +8q$.  If any one of them is positive there there are two distinct roots.  Is there any way all three of them are non-positive?  If not you are done.  If yes, under what conditions and what happens then?

Um... this isn't true.  If $p=q=r=s=0$ this equation is $-x^6=0$ which only has one real root.

Why are you assuming the only option is one multiple root and the rest complex.  Why not all complex or one multiple and no complex.  Why are you assuming if one is multiple it has to be that $p^2 \ge 12q$ while the other two have $<$.  Why not $r^2 \ge 4q$ and $p^2 < 12q$?

My assumption is without the loss of generality. If you work it out the way you have mentioned, you will arrive at a similar conclusion as that of mine.

Assume all the roots are complex.
Imposing that the discriminant are negative you get
$$
\begin{align}
&36q> p^2\\
&4q>r^2\\
&4q<-s^2
\end{align}
$$
as squares are positive the last two inequalities have no solution.
As complex roots of polynomial with real coefficients are complex coniiugate this implies that there are two real roots


This is a bit incomplete. Following your argument to the letter, you only managed to show there is at least one real root. I would suggest to throw a large inequality somewhere to account for the "exactly one real root" case.

@rafilou2003 in a polynomial with real coefficient complex roots are coniugate (or if you prefer there is always an even number of complex roots of a real polynomial). I will add the clarification

I was talking about the real repeated root case, which technically counts as one

@rafilou2003 unless specified I will count the roots with multiplicity, otherwise $p=q=r=s=0$ contraddict the statement of the OP

You are correct, didn't notice that

@Marco I would be grateful to you if you provide a little more insight on how did you arrive to the conclusion that the roots are with multiplicity?

@Jakamousepro The roots does not need to have multiplicity 2, but they can. What I have proven (and you also did) is that at least one of the 3 quadratics have a non-negative discriminant. This is enough to prove that one of the polynomial has 2 (not necessarly distinct) real roots

@Marco Thank you!
